# How do I combine angular and some additional modules into one minified file with a source map?

Tags: angularjs, uglifyjs

What I’m trying to do is take angular and some of the additional modules like route, cookies... and combine them into one minified js file with a source map. I'm using grunt as my build tool. Right now I just concat the pre minified versions of angular and modules all together into one file. The problem is the file has multiple source maps and does not work. I have been thinking about using grunt to take the non minified version and concat them into one and then uglify them and make one source map. I just don't know if that's a good idea. I also have read I will have to use ng-annotate if I go this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you suggest is what I do, except with gulp. I concat all my javascript files into one file, minify the code, and generate a source map for just the one file.

I also do use ng-annotate. It's pretty convenient and allows you to stop thinking about dependency injection - it just takes care of it for you.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are concating angular.js along with your app code and then minifying it correct? What package are you using to minify?

Comment: I am packaging my dependencies separately from my application's codebase. So angular/ui-router/angular-resource/etc are all being packaged into a vendors.js file, then minified. Separately, I am packaging my app's codebase/components/etc into an app.js, then minified. I use gulp standard packages for this - `gulp-concat`, `gulp-uglify`, `gulp-sourcemaps`.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Any reason you divide them into vender and app, cacheing perhaps?

Comment: Keeps dependencies separate from the app code is the main reason. I also think there's a benefit to having somewhat smaller filesizes so that dependencies and the application can download asynchronously instead of one huge chunk. Also caching is another benefit. Also likely the vendors won't change much so we don't throw them into the build process unnecessarily.